# Computing log-posterior for large variance priors

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, prior, posterior, quasi-likelihood

Let's say that some quantity is modelled by a time-dependent Poisson distribution,
$$
y(t) \sim \text{Pois}(\mu(t))
$$

where
$$
\mu(t) = \alpha_0 \exp(-\alpha_1 e^{-\alpha_2 t})
$$
and $\alpha_k > 0$ for $k = 0, 1, 2$

For a given parameter $\theta_k = log(\alpha_k)$, I computed the log-likelihood and obtained the following result and data $\mathcal{D}_i$,
$$
l(\vec{\theta}|\mathcal{D}_i) = -e^{\theta_0 - \eta(\theta_1, \theta_2)} + y_i \theta_0 - y_i \eta(\theta_1, \theta_2)
$$
where $\eta(\theta_1, \theta_2) \equiv \exp{(\theta_1 - e^{\theta_2} t_j)}$

Now I would like to compute the log-posterior for large variance priors. I use the equation for $\mu(t)$ as the prior but I'm not so sure it is what I should use. With that, I get the following result for the prior,

\begin{align*}
 P(\vec{\theta}) 
  &= e^{\theta_0} \exp(-e^{\theta_1} e^{-e^{\theta_2} t_j}) \\ 
  &= e^{\theta_0} \exp(e^{\theta_1 - e^{\theta_2} t_j}) \\
  &= e^{\theta_0} \exp(\eta(\theta_1, \theta_2))
\end{align*}

I find then the log-posterior,
\begin{align*}
 p(\vec{\theta}|\mathcal{D}_i)
  &\propto l(\vec{\theta}|\mathcal{D}_i) \cdot P(\vec{\theta}) \\
  &=\left( -e^{\theta_0 - \eta(\theta_1, \theta_2)} + y_i \theta_0 - y_i \eta(\theta_1, \theta_2) \right) \cdot e^{\theta_0} \exp(\eta(\theta_1, \theta_2))
\end{align*}

Does that make sense ?

Comment: Sorry it was $\alpha_k > 0$

Comment: The equation defining $\mu(t)$ is not a probability distribution, involves an unspecified $t_j$, so unfortunately, the derivation of the posterior does not make sense.

Comment: $t$ is a discret time parameter ranging from $t = 10$ days to $t = 500$ days by step of $10$. Since I have no information on the distribution of $\mu(t)$, should I assume a uniform distribution like $U(0,1)$ or should I infer a distribution from the analytical expression for $\mu$ ?

Comment: Since $\mu(t)$ depends on $\alpha_k$ $(k=0,1,2)$, the prior should be defined on $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$, no on $\mu_t$ or on $(\mu(10),\ldots,\mu(500))$.